# What is the button on the end of the taskbar to clear the screen called?

Tags: windows-7

I don't know what the button on the end of the Windows taskbar which clears the screen is called. Anybody know?

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is just called the "Show Desktop Button"

[image]

Answer (score 14):

"Show Desktop Button" is its name. But it doesn't just hide all windows. If you click it again, it will show them again, just as they were before you pressed it the first time. <kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut does the same. Basically, it toggles between all your visible windows and desktop.

Also, if you want to hide all windows, press <kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. Pressing this combination multiple times will not bring up the hidden windows, you'll have to do it manually. A useful "boss-key".

Comment: except if you use it to show your desktop so that you can open a new window, you then can not press it again to bring your other windows back.  One of the most annoyingly half implemented parts of win7.

Comment: *"If you click it again, it will show them again, just as they were before you pressed it the first time."* - Really?! I wish I knew that trick earlier...

Comment: Pressing `Winkey` + `Shift` + `M` brings back the windows that are minimized using `Winkey` + `M`.